# Q:Global name is not defined when running testsuite with py.test

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I have a unittest suite verifying configuration setting of multiple remote servers via ssh (using paramiko) running properly. I wanted to integrate it into Jenkins using pytest output however the testsuite running with py.test gives me the following error:

NameError: global name '_ssh' is not defined

```
$ py.test --junitxml results.xml bsr-multinode.py -v -x
======= test session starts ===============
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.11+, pytest-2.9.1, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1 -- /usr/bin/python
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /home/dany, inifile: pytest.ini
collected 150 items 

bsr-multinode.py::myClass::test_test1 FAILED

------ generated xml file: /home/dany/results.xml ---------------
============ FAILURES ======================
__  myClass.test_test1 __________________________

self = <bsr-multinode.myClass testMethod=test_test1>

    def test_test1(self):
>       self.assertRegexpMatches(_ssh.execute('netstat -nlp | grep -vi unix | grep sshd'),'sshd','sshd not running')
E       NameError: global name '_ssh' is not defined

bsr-multinode.py:121: NameError
!!! Interrupted: stopping after 1 failures !!!!!!!
============= 1 failed in 0.50 seconds ====

$ python bsr-multinode.py 
ms-100-00
.......F..FFF.F.F.F.F.F.....F..F...
Ran 150 tests in 49.724s

FAILED (failures=35)
db-100-01
.......F..FFF.F.F.F.F.F.....F..F...
Ran 150 tests in 56.816s

FAILED (failures=56)
```

I tried different things with no help. Any clue would be welcome. Here is my code:

```
servers=["192.168.1.1","192.168.1.2"]

class sshClient:
    def __init__(self,host):
       self.client = paramiko.SSHClient()
       self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
       try:
           self.client.connect(host,username="account", password="password")
       except paramiko.SSHException:
           print "Connection Error"

    def close(self):
        if self.client is not None:
            self.client.close()
            self.client = None

    def execute(self, command):
        stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command(command)
        output=''.join(stdout.readlines())
        return output

class myClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_test1(self):
    self.assertRegexpMatches(_ssh.execute('netstat -nlp | grep -vi unix | grep sshd'),'sshd','sshd not running')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for server in servers:
        _ssh = sshClient(server)
        hostname = _ssh.execute('hostname')
        hostname = hostname.replace("\n","")
        print hostname
        runner = unitest.TextTestRunner()
        unittest.main(testRunner=runner,exit=False)
```

Comment: Does it work locally?(I am not sure about self.assertRegexMatches(_ssh)) do you have _ssh variable in that class avaliable?

Comment: Yes, the testsuite worked properly when running from python:
$ python bsr-multinode.py 
ms-100-00
.......F..FFF.F.F.F.F.F.....F..F..................F...
...
Ran 150 tests in 49.724s
FAILED (failures=35)
db-100-01
.......F..FFF.FFF.FFF.FF...FF..F............
..
Ran 150 tests in 56.816s

FAILED (failures=56)

Comment: You get a lot of failures there as well, and it seems you get the same with pytest (aborting after the first one because of `-x`) - so I don't see where the issue is?

Comment: Failed test are expected but all test are executed when running standalone while with pytest I got the global name not defined and no test have been executed.

Comment: Tried also with nose and nose2 and got the same issue.